# JQuery smooth scroll to positions inside DIV with overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a div full of content (dates). At anyone time you can see 5 dates on screen. I want the arrow on the right of the div to scroll the div showing the next 5 until the end and visa versa the arrow on the left scrolling left by 5 dates until it reaches the end.

How can this be achieved.

Some information::

- each date is 50px wide including all padding
- There are 90 to 120 dates
- Only 5 can be seen at once.
- The dates scroll as part of the webkit systems on mobile devices already.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: How does this webkit scroll work?

Comment: Giving us your HTML and your CSS would make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var offset = 0; // current scrolling "amount"
$('#right-arrow').click(function() {
    offset += (50 * 5); // add a total width of 5 items to the scrolling amount

    if (offset > (number_of_dates * 50)) {
        offset = number_of_dates * 50; // don't exceed this limit
    }

    $('#div-to-scroll').animate({
        'margin-left': '-' + offset + 'px'
    });
});


$('#left-arrow').click(function() {
    offset -= (50 * 5);

    if (offset < 0) {
        offset = 0; // don't exceed this limit
    }

    $('#div-to-scroll').animate({
        'margin-left': offset + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: Very good. I've changed a few bits of it. The problem is that the same area has iScroll4 applied to it for touch screen devices that is now offset and will not function properly as it does not use margins to justify its location. Any idea what it does and how to change your script accordingly

Comment: if the problem are the margins, you could give position:absolute; to #div-to-scroll, and with the script change its left position instead of margin-left.

Comment: I used a JQuery plugin called scrollTo to and adjusted your offset to scrollTo instead of margins. This has worked but now iScroll4 does not set a new offset when it moves so when the button is clicked it scrolls back to where it was before a touch scroll was done and then scrolls along by 5. Not a huge problem I know but not perfect and I am a perfectionist. I'll post a new question with a fiddle and see if anyone wants to take it on. Many Thanks

Comment: Good, I will check it then to see if we manage to fix that problem. Just a sidenote, I also tried that plugin but found many times it acted weird with strange/unwanted behaviors. In the end if you only need to scroll a item in one direction is better to do a self job like I suggest this way you keep things simple and you are sure you know what the script is doing all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about markup and CSS here? Because the jQuery stuff is pretty easy.

Outermost, you need a wrapper div. This needs to have `overflow: hidden;`, and a fixed/auto width. Inside that you place the div that contains the dates, it should also be fixed width, but very large, to fit all the dates. It should have `position: relative;`. The dates should be aligned using `float: left;`. Then your jQuery can animated the "left" CSS property of the dates div. E.g. if someone clicks the right arrow, then `$('#dates').css('left', $('dates').position().left - 50 + 'px');`. You can also animate the change using [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [CSS3 transitions](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could wrap each "page" (5 items) and scroll it with jQueryTools Scrollable to achieve this: http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

(just arrange it properly and scroll `<ul>`'s instead of `<div>`'s for that matter)

but it's better to understand how you do things like that in general.

the way of doing such things is wrapping the date container inside a DIV that has overflow:hidden set, and then pulling the the container up [x] pixels as the wrapper's height.

The HTML + CSS would be:

```
> <div class="wrapper" style="overflow:hidden; height:250px;">    // height is 5 x 50px per li for this purpose
>   <ul class="datesContainer" style="position:relative;">
>   <li> some date </li>
>   <li> another date </li>
>   ...
>   </ul>
> </div>
> <a id="goUp">Go Up</a>
```

And the jQuery would be something like this:

```
>   $("#goUp").click(function(){
          newOffset = parseInt($(this).css("top"))-250
          $(".datesContainer").animate("top",newOffset,500);
    }
```

I've used constant numbers for this example, basically you get $(".wrapper").height() to make it work for any height.
Also, you'll have to handle it when the user reaches the bottom of your list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jose Faeti's answer, I've changing the logic a bit and made it vertical scroll instead of horizontal (original question was for horizontal, but this is another angle of the same basic strategy):

HTML:

```
<div id="up-arrow">UP</div>
<div id="rows-wrapper">
  <div id="rows-container">
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 1</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 2</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 3</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 4</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 5</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 6</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 7</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 8</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 9</div>
    <div class="row-item">Row Item 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="down-arrow">DOWN</div>
```

CSS (you'll need to fill in the blanks, but this shows where the overflow should go):

```
#product-card-wrapper {
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row-item {
    float:left;
}
```

JS:

```
var offset = 0; // current scrolling "amount"
var row_height = $('.row-item').height() + 10; //calc height of item in row and compensate for some bottom margin
var number_of_rows = Math.ceil(($('.row-item').length / 2) * 10) / 10; //calc number of rows and round up (dividing by 2 as there are 2 items per row)
$('#down-arrow').click(function() {
    if ((Math.abs(offset)) > (number_of_rows * row_height)-row_height) {
        // don't exceed this limit
    } else {
        offset -= (row_height);
    $('#rows-container').animate({
        'margin-top': offset + 'px'
    });
    }
});

$('#up-arrow').click(function() {
    offset += (row_height);
    if (offset > 0) {
    offset = 0; // don't exceed this limit
    }

    $('#rows-container').animate({
        'margin-top': offset + 'px'
    });
});
```